# Android : How to get a notification icon with transparent background and the biggest possible size in the status bar

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I'm trying to build programmatically  a notification that would write some number and unit inside a transparent icon in the status bar. I want to do something like the app netspeed does : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nisargjhaveri.netspeed

I first create a bitmap and then an icon via Icon.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(bitmap) I then feed them to respectively the notification via
.setLargeIcon(bitmap)

and

.setSmallIcon(IconCompat.createFromIcon(icon))

But Whatever I try I always get a rather small icon with black background.

TIA